# customizing google apps script methods using post for append data to sheet

Tags: reactjs, google-apps-script, google-sheets

currently i trying to send/append data to spreadsheet using google apps script, but if i click the `submit` button i want to the page not redirect  as https://www.selly.id/ if you try to send data from it form , it only change the UI and the data is sended to sheet, 
so do i must change it using JS , or other methods

here is my current website https://selly-midtrans.herokuapp.com/ , but it now working correctly yet

```
function doPost(e){
  var vals=[];
  vals.push(new Date());
  for(var i in e.parameter){
    vals.push(e.parameter[i]);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1gMjG4MWTLzoPncVkJ_nGimYdiXULzCvYt5nvqCf4Z4o").appendRow(vals);
//  return ContentService.createTextOutput("added");
}

function doGet(e){
  var vals=[];
  vals.push(new Date());
  for(var i in e.parameter){
    vals.push(e.parameter[i]);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1gMjG4MWTLzoPncVkJ_nGimYdiXULzCvYt5nvqCf4Z4o").appendRow(vals);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("added");
}
```

here's my form

```
<form  id="form" method="post" action="https://script.google.com/a/41studio.com/macros/s/AKfycbwlP_LSQSRHI0wIoJtfwFXiAJttawlYV5dN1PFpAOMtdZ2D-Iz7/exec" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="text" name="newletter_name" placeholder="Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="newletter_email" placeholder="Email"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe"/>
</form>
```

I'm Kind Of Confused

FYI : im develop it using react JS

Comment: Have you tried sending the data via ajax/axios rather than a form submit? A

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a POST request from your form, you can use Javascript to do it for you and prevent the page from reloading.

Since you are using react the trigger is `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}`

Then create the method to handle the submit, something like below. YO

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); //this prevents the page from reloading
  const opts = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: ...  //fix this to whatever parameters you are passing
  };

  fetch(URL, opts)
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

The documentation for [using the fetch API is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

You can use a package like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to handle the fetch request much more easily.

I made a [blog post](http://gtrainerdemo.jordanrhea.com/teachertools/contact-form) about using the `doPost(e)` in Google Apps Script however, it doesn't use ReactJS so it might not help.